# Xamarin - What apk package(s) should I use when I publish my app to the google store

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, apk

With Visual Studio 2019 I created a archive folder that contains 3 signed-apk files for the app I plan on publishing to the google store.

In the signed-apks folder the file names are:

```
com.blah1.app.apk
com.blah1.app-arm64-v8a.apk
com.blah1.app-armeabi-v7a.apk
```

Which one(s) should I use?  The Google Play Console seems to let me add all 3.  Any other information you also provide would be great as well.

Thanks.

Comment: You should actually use an Android App Bundle as this succeeds multiple APKs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upload all three. you are generating an apk per ABI

[From the documentation:](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

> Multiple APK support is a feature on Google Play that allows you to
>   publish different APKs for your application that are each targeted to
>   different device configurations. Each APK is a complete and
>   independent version of your application, but they share the same
>   application listing on Google Play and must share the same package
>   name and be signed with the same release key. This feature is useful
>   for cases in which your application cannot reach all desired devices
>   with a single APK.